# Using values from one react component to create a ternary statement within another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm going to try my best to explain my issue (I'm fairly new to all of this).

For starters. I have a component called **LargestSale24H** that returns a card with data from an API. Specifically it returns 3 cards; each showing one of 3 of the largest transactions in the last 24 hours. For each transaction it shows the username, user avatar, amount of transaction and date. Here is that return:

```
if (buyer != null) {
          return (
            <Container key={sale_id}>
              <Card key={buyer}>
                {/* <Badges account={buyer} /> */}
                <UserAvatars user={buyer} />
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <Link href={'/user/' + buyer}>
                  <Button>{buyer}</Button>
                </Link>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                {salePrice} {listing_symbol}
                <br></br>
                {parseTimestamp(updated_at_time)}
              </Card>
            </Container>
          );
        }
```

Additionally, I've created another component called **Badges** which is supposed to take each user, in this case **buyer**, and find all items that they own. This is what the code for badges looks like.

```
function Badges({ account }) {
  const [assets, setAssets] = useState<Assets>();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/accounts/' + account
      );
      const { data } = await res.json();
      setAssets(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (!assets) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Spinner />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {assets?.collections?.length > 0 &&
        assets.collections.map((collectionParent, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>{collectionParent.collection.collection_name}</li>
          );
        })}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default Badges;
```

Currently I have **Badges** commented out from **LargestSale24H**, when I bring it back, it lists out all the items that the user has. Items look something like **123456789**. I'm listing them out only as a test buy ideally I want to create a ternary statement that says something like "if this account has this item in their collection, return A, else return  B". Incase you are wondering why, it's because I want to return one time of **UserAvatar** if they own a specific item, otherwise, I want to keep the one that's listed.

I tried doing this:

```
 if (<Badges account={buyer} /> == 523252144314) {
          return (
            <Container key={sale_id}>
              <Card key={buyer}>
                <UserAvatars user={buyer} />
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <Link href={'/user/' + buyer}>
                  <Button>{buyer}</Button>
                </Link>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                {salePrice} {listing_symbol}
                <br></br>
                {parseTimestamp(updated_at_time)}
              </Card>
            </Container>
          );
        }
```

Now, I didn't expect that to work but since I'm still learning all this, I figured I'd give this a try. Normally I would be googling this but I don't exactly know what I have to do. I know that I'm receiving a list item per buy of what they own, that works fine. But What I need to do is basically go through each item and compare it with what's in the ternary statement basically deciding if it's true or false. I just don't know how to do that. I feel like perhaps listing the values is the incorrect thing to do. Perhaps my logic is incorrect and I should be doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't use the jsx representation of a component in an if statement like you did.

In your `Badges` component you could do something like this:

```
return (
    <ul>
        {assets?.collections?.length > 0 &&
            assets.collections.map((collectionParent, index) => {
                if(collectionParent.collection.collection_name){
                    return  <li key={index}>A</li>
                }else{
                    return <li key={index}>B</li>
                }
            })}
    </ul>
);
```

But that seems so obvious, that I am not sure if that is what you are asking for. In that case, I need more clarity.